# Минимальное расстояние в графе

Tags: c++, алгоритм, графы

> Дано связный невзвешенный граф с N вершинами N-1 ребром. И также подграф етого графа P. Найти вершину от которой расстояние до каждой вершины подграфа P будёт минимальна и вывести само расстояние.

Буду рад любой идеи к решению, а сейчас немного про ограничения:

```
TIME : 2 сек
MEMORY : 256 МБ
N, K <= 10^5, где N количество вершин графа, а K количество вершин подграфа P
```

Так же наведу пример для наглядности:

```
N K
| |
8 4

Далее задано N - 1 ребер:

1 2
1 3
1 4
4 6
4 5
5 7
5 8

Далее K чисел через пробел, вершины подграфа P:

2 5 6 7

Ответ: 
6
```

***Моя попытка, которая идёт на лимит времени:***

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int n;

int BFS(vector<vector<int>> graph, int from, int to)
{
    vector <bool> mark(1 + n, true);
    vector <int> dist(1 + n, 0);

    queue <int> Q;
    Q.push(from);
    mark[from] = false;

    while (!Q.empty())
    {
        int v = Q.front();
        Q.pop();

        for (int i = 0; i < graph[v].size(); ++i)
        {
            int vert = graph[v][i];
            if (mark[vert])
            {
                mark[vert] = false;
                dist[vert] = 1 + dist[v];
                Q.push(vert);
            }
        }
    }

    return dist[to];
}

int main()
{
    int m;
    cin >> n >> m;

    vector <vector<int>> graph(1 + n);

    for (int i = 0; i < (n - 1); ++i)
    {
        int u, v;
        cin >> u >> v;
        graph[u].push_back(v);
        graph[v].push_back(u);
    }

    vector <int> P(m);
    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i)
    {
        cin >> P[i];
    }

    int ans = INT_MAX;
    for (int from = 1; from <= n; from++)
    {
        int cur = 0;
        for (auto to : P)
        {
            int dist = BFS(graph, from, to);
            cur += dist;
        }

        ans = min(ans, cur);
    }

    cout << ans << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: вам нужно минимизировать максимальное расстояние или сумму? Если максимальное то надо найти диаметр подграфа P. Если сумму - придётся делать динамику.

Comment: мне нужно найти минимальную сумму расстояний от оптимальной вершины до каждой вершины подграфа P :)

Comment: тобеш если взять оптимальную вершину то сумма минимальных расстояний от нее до каждой вершины подграфа P ето и есть ответ

Comment: окей, так тут еще и динамика :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решение, которое работает линейно от числа вершин в графе.

```
vector< vector<int> > G;
vector<char> isP;
int K;

int dfs2(int v, int p, int l){
    int res = 0;
    for (auto next : G[v])
        if (next !=p)
            res+=dfs2(next,v, l+1);
    if (isP[v])
        res+=l;
    return res;
}


int dfs(int v, int p){
    int res = isP[v];
    for (auto next : G[v])
        if (next !=p)
            res+=dfs(next,v);
    if (res > K/2){
        cout << dfs2(v,-1,0)<<" "<<v<<endl;
        exit(0);
    }
    return res;
}
```

Запускаемый пример https://ideone.com/eIbkNs

Мы находим первую вершину, в поддереве которой не меньше половины всех отмеченных вершин. И от неё уже считаем расстояния.

Почему это оптимальная вершина. Давайте возьмём любую вершину (X), вычислим от неё все сумму расстояний. Если в каком-то её потомке больше половины вершин, то переместив X в эту вершину, мы уменьшим сумму. Т.к. больше половины путей станут на 1 короче, а меньше половины на 1 длиннее. Повторив это пока возможно, мы получим вершину, в поддереве которой не меньше половины всех отмеченных, но для каждого потомка это не выполняется. Почему минимум расстояний не зависит от выбора исходной вершины X - доказывается аналогично.

Доказательство использует ацикличность графа (упражнение - где именно). Напомню, что связный граф с N-1 ребром и N вершинами - дерево и, естественно, не содержит циклов.

Comment: Ловко ;) Может быть, стоит отметить, что связный граф с N-1 рёбер есть дерево, чтобы было понятно, почему речь идёт о деревьях.

Comment: Кстати для примера ответ может быть и вершина 4 и так же 5.

Comment: @GGO условие менять не надо. Оно такое и должно быть. А можете ссылку на тест систему дать, сам проверю.

Comment: https://algotester.com/en/ArchiveProblem/Display/40135

Comment: все окей, только я не понимаю почему у меня в тестувалке неверный ответ... Xммм кстати, если вот ето условие (res > K / 2) 'если' сменить на другое, то еще меньше даёт :)

Comment: @GGO замените `int` на `long long` в dfs2 там сумма может быть  около 10^10/2 что больше разрядности 32 бит. трогать не буду в ответе. Кстати, 25 тест - последний чуть что)

Comment: понятно, спасибо за наглядность @pavel :D

Comment: я уже понял в чём моя проблема, я не учёл то что граф связный, а этот факт что вы сказали очень кстати то :)

Answer (score 2):

Для начала, я бы упросил задачу. Например, посчитал бы сумму расстояний от одной произвольной вершины до P. Тут можно поспользоваться тем фактом, что граф связный, то есть из любой его вершины можно дойти до любой. Таким образом, используя поиск в ширину, можно нвйти минимальные расстояния от вершины до P за линейное время (кол-во вершин + кол-во ребер). Код нв Java

```
public  static int GetDistSum(ArrayList<Integer>[] graph, HashSet<Integer> p, int from)
{
    Queue<Integer> q = new LinkedList<>();
    boolean[] visited = new boolean[graph.length];

    int steps = 0;
    int sumSteps = 0;
    int pVisited = 0;

    q.add(from);
    while (q.isEmpty() == false)
    {
        int levelCount = q.size();
        for(int i=0; i<levelCount; i++)
        {
            int v = q.poll();
            if (visited[v]) continue;

            visited[v] = true;
            if (p.contains(v)) {
                sumSteps+=steps;
                pVisited++;
                if (pVisited == p.size()) return sumSteps;
            }

            for(Integer c : graph[v])
            {
                if (visited[c]) continue;
                q.add(c);
            }
        }
        steps++;
    }
    return sumSteps;
}
```

Ну и теперь осталось пройти по всем вершинам и найти минимум.

```
public static int GetMinDist(ArrayList<Integer>[] graph, int[] p)
{
    HashSet<Integer> pset = new HashSet<>();
    for(int i : p) pset.add(i);

    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    for(int i=1; i<graph.length; i++)
        min = Math.min(min, GetDistSum(graph, pset, i));

    return min;
}
```

То есть в результате сложность алгоритма будет `N*(N+G)`, где N - колв вершин, G - колво ребер. Но мы и так значем, что ребер будет `N-1`, то есть сложность становится `N(N+N-1) = 2N^2`, то есть квадратичная.

Пример вызова для случая из вопроса:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {    

    ArrayList<Integer>[] graph = new ArrayList[9];

    for(int i=0; i<graph.length; i++) graph[i] = new ArrayList<>();

    graph[1].add(2);
    graph[2].add(1);

    graph[1].add(3);
    graph[3].add(1);

    graph[1].add(4);
    graph[4].add(1);

    graph[4].add(5);
    graph[5].add(4);

    graph[4].add(6);
    graph[6].add(4);

    graph[5].add(7);
    graph[7].add(5);

    graph[5].add(8);
    graph[8].add(5);

    int[] p = {2, 5, 6, 7};

    System.out.println(GetMinDist(graph, p));
}
```

Так как граф ненаправленный, то каждое ребро добавляется в него дважды.

Результат:

```
6
```

У автора же проблема в том, что он вызывает BFS для каждой вершины P, что делает сложность в итоге кубической (если P=N).

Comment: 10^5 за квадрат. Не успеет все равно...

Comment: @pavel я вам верю, но в воскресенье вечером ничего лучше уже не придумаю. Разве что какой то кеш добавить, чтобы хранить все расстояния от одной вершины до другой и не пересчитывать их. Но это тоже будет что то типа квадрата, ну, или P*N.

Comment: Можно линейно за N. Простейшая динамика. Или даже жадно думаю хватит

Comment: Не совсем понял, как линейно найти все расстояния между множествами N и P, потому,если напишете решение, пинганите меня плиз, мне будет очень интересно поглядеть :)

Comment: Если коротко. Это первая вершина в которой при dfs(не b)  будет не меньше половины всех отмеченных вершин в её поддереве.

Comment: @pavel но ведь тут при dfs (или bfs) мы пройдем по всему графу с любой вершины?

Comment: @pavel я начинаю понимать, это что то типа если найти диаметр P и потом найти середину диаметра, то есть вершину, которая делит P примерно пополам, а такая вершина только одна, так как  у нас граф ациклический, то есть по сути дерево. Забавно получается.

Comment: Да. У нас и есть дерево.  N-1 ребро же. Но это не диаметр. Диаметр если бы максимум искали а не сумму

Comment: @pavel то есть по сути, ищем вершину с DFS, что линейно, потом от неё ищем расстояния с BFS, что тоже линейно. Круто, жду вашу реализацию, хотя вроде всё понятно теперь  :)

Comment: написал :D вроде бы коротко получилось.

Comment: @pavel годнота, спасибо! :)